# How to delete the history of joining some channels of a peer in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'v used the tutorial[tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peer-chaincode-devmode.html) for many times to try to run a chaincode in the development mode of Hyperledger Fabric. I thought I had messed the things up and deleted the "fabric" folder once before. However, when I was trying again to creat a channel name "ch1", using a new "fabric" folder I downloaded, an error came out:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'ch1': error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: proposed update requires that key [Group]  /Channel/Application be at version 0, but it is currently at version 1
```

It seems the channel "ch1" is already created. I used the instruction:

```
peer channel list
```

to query how many channel I've created. The result turns out to be:

```
 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Channels peers has joined: 
ch
ch1
ch2
```

It seems though I'm using a new "fabric" folder, the peer node remains all the channels I created before. I'm a new beginner and have little knowledge about how to fix this. I  really want to know how to delete all the history of the peer node and the orderer node I created before to have a new start. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This may be caused by the remaining volume of the peer docker container that you deleted. Clear the docker volume by executing the `docker volume prune` command and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was not using the docker, but woking in my PC environment...

Comment: Clean the `fileSystemPath` in your peer configuration. The default value is `/var/hyperledger/production`, and channel information will remain under the directory path, and for a new network, you need to clean it.